# Node js knex and mssql error - 'TypeError: _this.driver.Connection is not a constructor'

Tags: sql-server, node.js

Not a question, more of a heads up in case anyone else encounteres this - While setting up a new node project, I want to use knex to access a MSSQL database server.  I'm initializing knex with this:

```
{
client: 'mssql',
connection: {
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    server: 'localhost',
    database:'testdb'
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
    }
}
```

I get the error:  'TypeError: _this.driver.Connection is not a constructor'.  After a lot of googling, I couldn't find anything with this error message, so I thought I'd post a heads up here.

I installed the latest knex, mssql, and msnodesqlv8 packages.  And that's the problem.  As of mssql v4.x, knex and mssql don't play nice (for now).  I was able to fix this by downgrading the mssql package to 3.3.

Comment: Thank you for posting this!  I ran into the same problem, after a lot of googling I ran across this and rolling back mssql version to 3.3 worked

Comment: @quack Feel free to mark my answer as the solution if this helped.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is exactly as is stated at the end of the question.

"I installed the latest knex, mssql, and msnodesqlv8 packages. And that's the problem. As of mssql v4.x, knex and mssql don't play nice (for now). I was able to fix this by downgrading the mssql package to 3.3."

I was able to solve the problem successfully with this solution also.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in a TypeScript project, and the ultimate culprit was that I had added a folder into my project that had the same name as the official npm package for the Knex client. For example, I was using `client : "pg"` which meant that internally it did a require("pg") to load that client.

My project structure was like so:

```
/app/
  node_modules/
  src/
    pg/
      index.ts -> my personal pg connector library
    ... other folders and files
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
```

The root culprit was that I had an improper `baseUrl` in my `/app/tsconfig.json`. I had used `"baseUrl" : "./src"` which meant it was searching in the `/app/src` for `pg` and finding my own library, rather than looking in `/app/node_modules` as one would expect. Upon changing the `baseUrl` to `./` the error went away.